# PHP mail not working anymore

Tags: php, email, apt

I accidentally removed the perl package instead of the pear from my Ubuntu server and for some reason it uninstalled many packages, like php, mysql, etc... Why is that? does those packages depend on perl?

My question is that when I uninstalled this package, mail stopped working. I installed everything again but I can't get mail to work again. I am using the PHP function.

Is there a package I need to install? If so which is it?

Many thanks

Comment: You need to install an MTA (Exim, Postfix, Sendmail, whatever) and to configure the relayhost and servername (at least)... it is a Serverfault question though. Hence the close vote

Comment: I love questions with no code and `does not work` as description. They are are very stimulating for the mind.

Comment: What's the result of `echo test mail | mail my@email.address -s"test mail"`?

Comment: @Andy: there is no result

Comment: @Chris try searchings the logs for your MTA for your email address (ask Google if unsure) and see if the mail even made it into the queue/attempted delivery etc - only once it works from the command line return to debugging it from PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, you removed the mail transport agent, too, and did not reinstall it. Try installing a package like "sendmail".

Background: the mail function just passes the mail to an underlying mail transport agent. If there is none, it will fail. Most/many/some of these mail transport agents rely on perl.

Comment: I tried reinstalling postfix but it is still not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Here's one:  Stop assuming that everyone else here is telepathic and giving us problem reports such as "it is still not working", "I can't get mail to work", and "there is no result".  [Report your problems properly.](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/problem-report-standard-litany.html)